# Declined Flag question about "Not an answer"

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, specific-answer

So I recently got a flag declined so I'm just posting the question here to ensure I'm on the right track with what to flag.

The answer I flagged doesn't attempt to answer the question and just randomly gives code for some other purpose. So it's not a wrong answer, it just doesn't answer question.  So I flagged it for **but it does not answer the question** from the section "This was posted as an answer, but it does not answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether."

The answer is the bottom one in the "[How to parse a string to an int in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194465/how-to-parse-a-string-to-an-int-in-c/15441942#15441942)" post. The answer starts with "Here is a simple way to parse a string".

So should I really not flag this type of answer in the future? or was this declined a one-off that I should ignore while continuing to flag these?

Comment: Still requires technical knowledge to suss that out.  In which case it's your job to downvote it, not a mod's job to delete it.  Remember, we're just [monkeys with guns in there hands](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5G5dp.png), you don't want us making too many judgements.

Comment: It is an answer. A wrong answer, perhaps, or an answer to another question, but still an answer. It should be downvoted or commented as needed.

Comment: So basically, only flag it as not an answer when 1) its not an answer, 2) requires no code knowledge to see that (or something along those lines)?

Comment: Right. Some examples are "I have the same problem..." (should be a comment) or "Thanks for the answers!" (when the OP tries to respond to the other answerers).

Comment: That does make sense.  Might be good to explain that a bit more in the flagging faq as it's a bit non obvious (at least to me) :)

Answer (score 3):

So there issue there is that you feel that the OP mis-interpreted what the question is.  *They* thought that they were answering the question, but you disagree.  In such cases it's not the mod's job to determine who's right.  The post is still an answer.

If you feel that they didn't properly interpret the OP's question or didn't answer it fully then you should downvote them, optionally with a comment indicating what you feel is wrong with the post.

Flagging as not an answer should be for posts where even the poster doesn't think they're answering the question, such as asking clarifying questions, posting "me too" or "thanks", etc.  Basically anything that should have just been a comment.

Comment: That makes sense in general.  In this specific case I'm not even sure the person thought they were answering the question.  More like they were looking for a free code review

Comment: @greedybuddha If it's not blatantly obvious looking at the post then err on the side of assuming it's an answer and just downvote/comment.  That's really the moral of the story here.

Comment: Thanks @servy, it's clear to me now. That's why I asked the question